# Defining a fitness function in the genetic algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, function, genetic, fitness

I'm in the process of developing a simple application that uses the genetic algorithm for scheduling a timetable. I had a look at various examples and most of them appear to be using the algorithm to reach the initial specified solution in a various amount of generations, and not other solutions based on constraints.

For example, in main class:

```
FitnessFunction.setSolution("0001012002");
```

output:

```
compile:
run:
Generation: 1 Fittest: 5
Generation: 2 Fittest: 6
Generation: 3 Fittest: 7
Generation: 4 Fittest: 9
Solution found!
Generation: 4
Genes:
0001012002
```

I understand that I have to declare the fitness function in some way. For example 1 represents a day shift and 2 a night shift. My question is how do I add the constraint that 2 can follow 1 however, 1 cannot follow 2? Would I have to replace the initial specified solution with a series of constraints? and how would that look like in code?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Any solution that has 1 following 2 gets a fitness of 0. With that it won't really be ever considered for future generations.

Comment: ok, that's fair enough. But where do I define that constraint and how?

Comment: What package are you using?

Comment: I would try and change how the individual is generated. Tweak the rules for the initial random generation, crossover, and mutation so that an individual is not generated with an invalid sequence in the first place.